# MSI merge module from a full MSI package

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Can I reliably create a merge module from a regular MSI package like MySQL to merge it with my own installation?
WiX has appropriate tools for that, but what pitfalls should I expect from such translation?
What are alternatives for installing other MSI packages from my own package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a bootstrapper application.  The application would install your installation package and then the 3rd party application(s).

If you have InstallShield, a popular way to do this is to create an InstallScript-based bootstrapper which calls the MSI files.

Comment: I try to keep my package chaining simpler then that.  I'd usually wrap something like MySQL up as a setup prerequisite.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "No". Merge Modules do not support all of the tables in MSI files. A perfect translation from Merge Module to MSI will not be possible (except maybe in carefully contrived situations :).

The answer William gave about using a bootstrapper/chainer instead is the correct way to handle this situation.

Comment: I wish WiX had a bootstrapper.   InstallShield Setup Prereqs, Feature Prereqs and built-in MSI chaining since InstallShield X is one of the few features that keeps me from moving to a pure WiX environment.

Comment: WiX v3.6 will have a bootstrapper. It's called Burn (http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/Lets-talk-about-Burn) and it will rock (when we finally get it working)! :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the pitfalls of trying to take an MSI and create a MSM out of it is that MSMs don't have Error tables, so any error strings that you expect to reference from your MSI custom actions won't exist.